# Which Mistake in Webview based Android Browser Application?

Tags: java, javascript, android, browser, webview

I'm making an Android Browser Application. Its splash image opens after loading but afterward it crashes. I haven't found what mistake I have in MainActivity.java code.
When i run the code, my default AVD tells me that my application has crashed.

MainActivity.java

```js
package com.example.package;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity
  extends Activity
{
  private WebView a;
  @SuppressLint({"InlinedApi"})
  private BroadcastReceiver b = new a(this);
  
  public void a()
  {
    AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    localBuilder.setTitle("Google");
    localBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit?");
    localBuilder.setIcon(2130837505);
    localBuilder.setPositiveButton("YES", new d());
    localBuilder.setNegativeButton("NO", new e());
    localBuilder.show();
  }
  
  public void onBackPressed()
  {
    a();
  }
  
  protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    requestWindowFeature(2);
    setContentView(2130903042);
    this.a = ((WebView)findViewById(2131230720));
    this.a.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    this.a.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.a.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    this.a.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    this.a.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    this.a.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    this.a.setWebChromeClient(new b(this));
    this.a.setDownloadListener(new c());
    this.a.setWebViewClient(new f());
  }
  
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu)
  {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(paramMenu);
    paramMenu.add(0, 1, 0, "Home").setIcon(2130837506);
    paramMenu.add(0, 2, 0, "Downloads").setIcon(2130837504);
    paramMenu.add(0, 3, 0, "Back").setIcon(2130837506);
    paramMenu.add(0, 4, 0, "Forward").setIcon(2130837505);
    paramMenu.add(0, 5, 0, "Refresh").setIcon(2130837509);
    return true;
  }
  
  public boolean onKeyDown(int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent)
  {
    if ((paramInt == 4) && (this.a.canGoBack()))
    {
      this.a.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(paramInt, paramKeyEvent);
  }
  
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem paramMenuItem)
  {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(paramMenuItem);
    switch (paramMenuItem.getItemId())
    {
    default: 
      return false;
    case 1: 
      this.a.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
      return true;
    case 3: 
      this.a.goBack();
      return true;
    case 5: 
      this.a.reload();
      return true;
    case 4: 
      this.a.goForward();
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  protected void onPause()
  {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(this.b);
  }
  
  @SuppressLint({"InlinedApi"})
  protected void onResume()
  {
    IntentFilter localIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE");
    registerReceiver(this.b, localIntentFilter);
    super.onResume();
  }
}
```

a.java

```js
package com.example.package;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.widget.Toast;

class a
  extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  a(MainActivity paramMainActivity) {}
  
  public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
  {
    Toast.makeText(paramContext, paramContext.getResources().getString(2131034114), 0).show();
  }

public static void finish() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
}

public static void startActivity(Intent localIntent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
}
}
```

g.java

```js
package com.example.package;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.TimerTask;

class g
  extends TimerTask
{
  private Object a;

g(splash paramsplash) {}
  
  public void run()
  {
    ((Activity) this.a).finish();
    Intent localIntent = new Intent();
    ((Activity) this.a).startActivity(localIntent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error message? Located in the log?

Comment: please mention the error line where crash occurs.

Comment: 11-13 11:03:17.094: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly the issue:

```
this.a = ((WebView)findViewById(2131230720));
```

The number "2131230720" is a `static` reference `int` to resources, in this case a layout view in your Activity. That number comes from R.java which is created when you "build" your project. Each time you perform a build, it will assign an integer to layout objects, strings, etc. that you define in XML in your `res` folder.

Using the integer value might work for a while (or is present in source code), but then you change your layouts (or other `R` objects like strings) or rebuild on a different machine, Android library, etc. and it doesn't work anymore;

That line should look like this:

```
this.a = ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.my_webview_layout_id));
```

where "my_webview_layout_id" is from your layout XML file. You should find the "id" of the XML defined object in an XML file in `res/layout` Use that `@+id` reference. That will keep track of changes to that static reference.

Then when you `build` or rebuild your Android app, it will create the `R.java` file with all of the appropriate references.

Comment: I m really Newbie. i found .apk file and i extract it. using apktool. but this source code many error. and R.java not found in source code. so only ids in Mainactivity.java  How solve this problem.

Comment: Got it. I edited my answer. It should explain how to fix it better.

Comment: ok means. example res/leyout/activity_main.xml code is <WebView android:id="@+id/webview" soved code is this.a = ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)); correct?

Comment: many many error. i think i can not do this. this is job for important me in my school practical. please help me Jim. i give all source code . pls you done the job. thanks